# how to make Infopath form textbox allow only alphabets

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I am trying to create a textbox in info path form with following criteria:

1.) Length should be 1-50 characters .

2.) It should not contain any digits.

3.) It should contain only letters from the alphabet.

**I tried the following pattern but it's not working**

```
FieldName | does not math pattern | [a-zA-Z]{1,50} | or
FieldName | does not math pattern | .*[a-zA-Z].*   |
```

following regex pattern work with allow special characters, but does not work in Infopath form

```
^[^0-9]+$
```

Comment: To set the maximum character for a text box, right click and go to Text Box properties and click the display tab. Look for the checkbox called "Limit text box to: x Characters".

Answer (score 1):

Following Custom Pattern Work for me.....

```
Field Name | does not match pattern | [a-zA-Z]([ ]*[a-zA-Z])*
```

[image]

Comment: If any one can let me know how a text box can only accept number but not letters?